# ACTION_GET_CONTENT : How to get file-ending when searching for multiple file types?

Tags: android, android-intent, sd-card, filepath

I am using an Intent to let the user select a file, and after the user has done that I want to know what kind of file-type the selected file is.

The intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
```

In my onActivityResult I want to extract the path from the intent through intent.getData() and all of it's "submethods" (getScheme(), getLastPathSegment() etc). However, I only get the Uri for the selected file.

Example of Uris':

```
Uri: content://media/external/audio/media/15185 //This is an audiofile
Uri: content://media/external/audio/media/20 //Another audiofile
Uri: content://media/external/images/media/20577 //this is a picture
Uri: file:///storage/emulated/0/testWed%20Apr%2017%2011%3A10%3A34%20CEST%202013 //This is a file
```

I've seen solutions of how to get the absolute path when the user is only allowed to chose images or audios. But how do I do I get the absolutePath (the real path with the name and file-ending, e.g. MyPicture.jpeg) if I want to allow the user to select from different file types?

The code I've been twiggling with to try to get the path-name in onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode

```
         String fileName = data.getData().getLastPathSegment().toString();
         System.out.println("Uri: " +data.getData().toString());
         File f = new File(fileName);
         System.out.println("TrYinG wIWThA Da FiLE: " +f.getAbsolutePath());
         System.out.println("FileNAME!!!: "+fileName);
```

Answer (score 5):

By file-ending I'm assuming you mean the file extension? (i.e. mp4)

If so you can use the `ContentResolver` to get the mimetype:

```
String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(sourceUri);
```

This will give you the mimetype assuming they are within the `MediaStore` which they should if you have the content `Uri`. so you'll get something like "image/png", "video/mp4", etc.

Then you can use `MimeTypeMap` to get the file extension from the mimetype:

```
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(mimeType);
```

Note that you should never substring the mimetype after "/" to get the extension as some mimetype does not use its extension such as ".mov" files which has the mimetype "video/quicktime"

Comment: While this is true, `getExtensionFromMimeType` will return the most common extension for the given MIME type. For instance, `xls` when a user selected `xlt`.